# How do I provide resiliency in AWS-DMS?

Tags: design-patterns, aws-dms, wal, logical-replication

I'm using `AWS-DMS` for replicating from `PostgreSQL` (as source endpoint) to `S3` (as target endpoint). I want to provide resiliency for the process.

Particularly, if the `DMS` goes down due to some reason, how do I ask it to start from the last point where it had read?

This translates to :

1. If `DMS` goes down during the full load, it should perform full load again and then move to CDC (change data capture).
2. If `DMS` goes down during CDC, it should resume from the point where it had gone down.

This poses some more challenges, like the write-ahead-logs corresponding to the point where it had gone down may no longer be present, and so it needs to do a full load again followed by CDC.

But, being optimistic, I would like a solution to the scenario when the log corresponding to the point of time when the DMS went down is still persisted.

Thanks.